# Tiger VNC service will not start

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, tigervnc

Hello I have installed Tiger VNC using RPM tigervnc-server-1.8.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.  I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo).  I am getting an error when trying to start the service using 
`systemctl start vncserver@:1.service`.

> error: "Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

When I run `systemctl status vncserver@:1.service` we get the following output

```
systemctl status vncserver@:1.service
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Fri 2019-04-26 10:47:54 EDT; 8s ago
  Process: 16077 ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver %i (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16068 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 26 10:46:24 localhost.localdomain vncserver[16068]: Killing Xvnc process ...
Apr 26 10:46:24 localhost.localdomain vncserver[16068]: Xvnc process ID 15840...
Apr 26 10:46:27 localhost.localdomain vncserver[16077]: New 'localhost.locald...
Apr 26 10:46:27 localhost.localdomain vncserver[16077]: Starting applications...
Apr 26 10:46:27 localhost.localdomain vncserver[16077]: Log file is /root/.vn...
Apr 26 10:46:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: PID file /home/root/.vnc/lo...
Apr 26 10:47:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service start ...
Apr 26 10:47:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desk...
Apr 26 10:47:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service e...
Apr 26 10:47:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I have done the following:

- Reinstalled the package
- Deleted everything from /tmp/.X11-uni folder
- Disabled the SELINUX
- Restarted server several times
- Changed the VNC password several times.